# Call ListView for a RaisedButton

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview, dart

I have a problem in my Flutter code.
I want to call the ListView _aAntwort() as a Text in a RaisedButton.
In the Simulation show a Error: "Stack Overflow".
Can anyone help me?

Thank you for the great support :)

```
                    RaisedButton(                              //StatefulWidget
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: _aAntwort(),                      //ERROR  
                    ),
                              

Widget randAnswer() {
var list = <String>['aAnswer', 'bAnswer', 'cAnswer', 'dAnswer'];

var rand = new Random();

int i = rand.nextInt(list.length);
iAnswer = list[i];

list.removeAt(i);

int ii = rand.nextInt(list.length);
iiAnswer = list[ii];

list.removeAt(ii);

int iii = rand.nextInt(list.length);
iiiAnswer = list[iii];

list.removeAt(iii);

int iiii = rand.nextInt(list.length);
iiiiAnswer = list[iiii];

list.removeAt(iiii);

return randAnswer();  }


 ListView _aAntwort() {
if (iAnswer == "aAnswer") {
  return aAnswer();
} else if (iAnswer == "bAnswer") {
  return bAnswer();
} else if (iAnswer == "cAnswer") {
  return cAnswer();
} else if (iAnswer == "dAnswer") {
  return dAnswer();
}
return _aAntwort();  }                                    // I want to call this one


ListView aAnswer() {
return ListView.builder(
   {.....
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please try to explain the problem once again.

Answer (score 0):

In _aAntwort() you return _aAntwort() as a default. This would result in an endless recursive call. You need to return something like aAnswer or noAnswer

```dart
ListView _aAntwort() {
  if (iAnswer == "aAnswer") {
    return aAnswer();}
  else if (iAnswer == "bAnswer") {
    return bAnswer();} 
  else if (iAnswer == "cAnswer") {
    return cAnswer();} 
  else if (iAnswer == "dAnswer") {
    return dAnswer();}
  return _noAnswer();  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't understand what you're getting at. Would it be possible for you to improve my code.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. But how can I now display _aAntwort() in my RaisedButton as text?

Comment: No clue what you mean.  aAntwort returns a widget to be displayed in the button. If you want to output a text, return Text(“what ever“);

Comment: Yes, I would like to display the widget aAnswer but the button is empty in the simulation.

Comment: Have you tested systematically? I would ensure any random random result calls aAnswer. Then in aAnswer I would only return a simple Text widget. If that doesn’t work, replace the aAnswer call with the Text widget. Make it as simple as possible until it works and then add complications step by step